# How to properly save an HICON from an IMAGELIST as an image file

Tags: c#, image, winapi, com

***My goal :***

Saving all `Window Icon Handle`(`HICON`) from inside an `HIMAGELIST` as multiple image files (`.png` or `.tiff`).

---

***My issue :***

After my saving procedure some images have poor quality but some don't.

I only noticed this problem on the images of folders with subfolders / subfiles.

[image: Saved HICON (.tiff)]

---

***My attempt :***

*Code background:*

- I'm using `Vanara` to help me with PInvoke calls and a lot more.
- The `HIMAGELIST`come from a `ListView` using the `ListViewMessage`:`LVM_GETIMAGELIST`.
- This method is part of a Shell Extension (I know, I shouldn't do that).

```cs
private void Saving()
{
    var hWnd = GetListViewHWnd(); // This is the Desktop SysListView32 HWND

    IntPtr lParam = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr pHil = SendMessage(hWnd, ListViewMessage.LVM_GETIMAGELIST, 0, ref lParam);

    var sHil = new SafeHIMAGELIST(pHil); // This is the IMAGELIST of the ListView

    var imageCount = sHil.Interface.GetImageCount(); // sHil.Interface == IImageList Interface

    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\Julien\Desktop\Icons\" + i + ".tiff"))
        {
            using (SafeHICON sHIcon = sHil.Interface.GetIcon(i, IMAGELISTDRAWFLAGS.ILD_NORMAL))
            {
                var bmpS = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                        sHIcon.DangerousGetHandle(),
                        Int32Rect.Empty,
                        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

                BitmapEncoder enc = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
                enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpS));
                enc.Save(fs);
            }
        }
    }

    sHil.Dispose();
}
```

Also :

```cs
var bmp = Bitmap.FromHicon(sHIcon.DangerousGetHandle());
bmp.Save(fs);
```

---

***FAQ :***

*Why I am using the listview imagelist and not `SHGetFileInfo` ?*

Because `SHGetFileInfo` will give me an `HICON` like that :

[image: bad]

for a folder that in reality look like this :

[image: good]

*What about passing `SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX` in your `SHGetFileInfo` ?*

Same thing, the icons of non-empty folders is not stored in the System Image List.

Since I can wrote my extension in C++ I am open to any solution written in C++ too.

***Edit :***
I tried to draw those glitched images using `IImageList.Draw()` and it seem to work. So clearly the problem come from how I create an image from an `HICON`.

[image]

```cs
var hdc = GetDC(notepadHWnd);
var dp = new IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS(
    hdc,
    new RECT(73, 73, 73, 73), 12,
    COLORREF.None,
    IMAGELISTDRAWFLAGS.ILD_NORMAL);

sHil.Interface.Draw(dp);
```

Comment: You should be using `IShellItemImageFactory` to get those icons, not grovelling in another process for private data.

Comment: What a coincidence, I just did it using `IShellItemImageFactory` and `SHCreateItemFromIDList`. The thing is, these dinamic folder icons are considered `Thumbnails` and not `Icons`. "SIIGBF_THUMBNAILONLY". I can throw my extension in the trash, but grovelling is always fun ya know :) I will post a solution, unless someone takes care of it before.

Comment: @JonathanPotter `IShellItemImageFactory.GetImage()` Work well for those `Thumbnails` but not with `"icons"` with the UAC shield. It return an icon without. I know about icon overlays, but the UAC shield is not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am stubborn I insisted with the `IMAGELIST` of the desktop listview.

I managed to get the icons / thumbnails from it. By drawing them in a in-memory device context.

No more glitched images.

```cs
private void Saving()
{
    var hWnd = GetListViewHWnd(); // Desktop SysListView32 HWND

    IntPtr lParam = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr pHil = SendMessage(hWnd, ListViewMessage.LVM_GETIMAGELIST, 0, ref lParam);

    var sHil = new SafeHIMAGELIST(pHil); // IMAGELIST of the ListView
    sHil.Interface.GetIconSize(out var cx, out var cy);

    var imageCount = sHil.Interface.GetImageCount(); // IImageList Interface
    var desktopHdc = new SafeHDC(GetDC(GetListViewHWnd()).DangerousGetHandle());
    var inMemoryHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(desktopHdc);

    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
    {
        var inMemoryBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(desktopHdc, cx, cy);

        SelectObject(inMemoryHdc, inMemoryBmp);

        var ilDp = new IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS(
            inMemoryHdc, 
            new RECT(0, 0, 0, 0), 
            i, 
            COLORREF.None,
            IMAGELISTDRAWFLAGS.ILD_NORMAL);

        sHil.Interface.Draw(ilDp);

        var bmpS = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                inMemoryBmp.DangerousGetHandle(), 
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty, 
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\Julien\Desktop\Icons\" + i + ".png"))
        {
            BitmapEncoder enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpS));
            enc.Save(fs);
        }

        inMemoryBmp.Dispose();
    }

    sHil.Dispose();
    desktopHdc.Dispose();
    inMemoryHdc.Dispose();
}
```

But as Jonathan Potter said it is **not** a good idea :

*A combination of `IShellItemImageFactory` and `SHCreateItemFromIDList` for example seem better.*